# TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object --> But object exists?

Tags: python, django

I am going mad over some code. Executing a program that is made to generate product suggestions randomly always yields to the error

> TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object

Yet I cant seem to see, where a NoneType object is returned. All print statements clearly indicate that I return an object and a Boolean. Unfortunately, it's quite a bit of code and I can't seem to reproduce the error with less code.

```
@staticmethod
def generate_random_product(variation):
    product_options = Product.objects.all()
    if not product_options:
        raise ValidationError(
            'PRODUCT CREATION FAILED HARD COULD NOT '
            'GENERATE RANDOM PRODUCT FOR: '
            + variation.name + '... PLEASE DELETE'
            'ALL DELIVERIES THAT WERE CREATED TODAY'
        )
    random_int = random.randint(0, (product_options.count() - 1))
    return product_options[random_int], True

def generate_random_product_from_category(self, variation, count):
    if count >= 10:
        return self.generate_random_product(variation, count)
    category = variation.package.category
    product_options = category.product_set.all()
    if not product_options:
        return self.generate_random_product(variation)
    random_int = random.randint(0, (product_options.count() - 1))
    return product_options[random_int], True

def generate_random_product_from_variation(self, variation, count):
    if count >= 5:
        return self.generate_random_product_from_category(variation, count)
    product_options = variation.product_set.all()
    if not product_options:
        return self.generate_random_product_from_category(variation)
    random_int = random.randint(0, (product_options.count() - 1))
    return product_options[random_int], False

def turn_variation_into_product(self, variation, delivery, count):
    if count < 15:
        # STEP 1: generate a random product
        random_product, failed_auto = self.generate_random_product_from_variation(variation, count)
        print(random_product)
        try:
            self.turn_variation_into_product(variation, delivery, count + 1)
        except (DeliveryItem.DoesNotExist) as e:
            print('return')
            print(random_product, failed_auto)
            return random_product, failed_auto
    else:
        delivery.delete()
        raise ValidationError(
            f'all options for {variation.name} are already '
            f'included in delivery {delivery.slug} ... tried '
            f'*{count}* times')


def create_delivery_items(self, delivery):
    schema_items = delivery.delivery_schema.schemaitem_set.all()
    for schema_item in schema_items:
        if schema_item.variation and not schema_item.product:
            random_product, failed_auto = self.turn_variation_into_product(schema_item.variation, delivery, 0)
            DeliveryItem.objects.create(
                quantity=schema_item.quantity,
                variation=schema_item.variation,
                product=random_product,
                original_type=schema_item.type,
                delivery=delivery,
                failed_auto=failed_auto,
            )
```

The error results from this line:

> random_product, failed_auto = self.turn_variation_into_product(schema_item.variation, delivery, 0)

**As you can see I have print statements right above the relevant return statement. But the print statement output the correct objects.**

Comment: A useful debugging step might be to comment out the problematic line and replace it with `result = self.turn_variation_into_product(schema_item.variation, delivery, 0)`.  Then you can inspect `result` and check to see if it has the value you'd expect.

Does your editor have a Python debugger built in?  A debugger is an invaluable tool for fixing logic errors.

Comment: Also, you may want to consider posting your code at the [Code Review stack exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).  As is, it's pretty tough to read/understand.  For example, the `generate_random_product` takes a single argument, `variation`, which is never used.  And `generate_random_product` is  called with _two_ arguments on line 16.

Comment: you are right - generate_random_product is called with two arguments in line 16, but variation is used in the message for the error.

Comment: putting the values into a `result` variable returned None as expected (since the error indicated NoneType) ... I simply dont understand how I can print out values right before returning but then they end up being `None`. In my head this is impossible ...

Comment: The cause of the error is shown in the duplicate question. But this really isn't an appropriate use of recursion, anyway.

Comment: yeah - in the meanwhile I realised that ... thank you for the help. This really was the right answer. Simple for loop with range solved this very easily.